# Renderer cell in JXTreeTable in base of content of a rows in java

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, jxtreetable

I'm using `JXTreeTable` from `org.jdesktop.swingx` to display a hierarchical structure data, so I've a some parent nodes and some child nodes attached to them.
What I want is to have different `renderer` for parent and child nodes.

Example: if JXTreeTable shows a parent node, the first column should be rendered as a String and the others with a JCheckBox else if JXTreeTable displays a child node, every cell should be rendered as a String.

First, I write in myTreeTableModel that extends `AbstractTreeTableModel` this piece of code:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
    if (column == 0)
        return String.class;
    return Boolean.class;
}
```

Everything is ok in parent node, but this shows an empty JCheckBox even in child nodes where I would like to have a blank cell. Returning `null` in method `getValueAt(....)` doesn't fix the problem. So, I thought to use Renderer class but I don't know where to start. I write a pseudo-renderer like this:

```
private class CustomCellRender implements TableCellRenderer {
   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
        int column) {
   setOpaque(true);
   JComponent component = null;
    if (value instanceof Parent_Node) {
        if (column == 0)
            component = new JLabel();
        else
            component = new JCheckBox();
    } else if (value instanceof Child_Node) {
        component = new JLabel();
    }
    return component;
   }
}
```

and I set this with:

```
myTreeTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomCellRender());
```

Could anyone tell where I'm wrong or give me some tips to solve this problem? Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** I tried to insert a test `System.out.println(...)` in method `getTableCellRendererComponent`but it's never called. So JTreeTable never runs this method.

Comment: In `getTableCellRendererComponent()`, I think you need to configure the component, so it will have to be `new JLabel(value.toString())` or such.

Comment: Also for performance reason, you should reuse the renderer components (JCheckBox, JLabel) by creating them in the constructor of the TableCellRenderer (Use 1 instance per distinct rendering logic)